# How to sync data with google sheets after online comeback in flutter

Tags: flutter, hive, spreadsheet

I was trying to build an offline todo based application in flutter. But when we click in send button, the data stored in hive should pushed to google sheets or other db. After all, the first data is only pushing to the db not all data.

this is the code of google sheet push data

[image]

Comment: it better to provide code as text, not as a screenshoot. 

also can you elaborate more details, what actually issue you faced ?